# Time to Click (seconds) in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I want to display with a widget in Google Analytics after which amount of seconds users are clicking a link.

How many users and click on external links is already tracked with the google tag manager.

I know it is possible, but I don't know how. I saw it in a video (https://gyazo.com/ea04edaf30af80611e5eabeff4f0b89a) but can't finde a solution.

Maybe someone has an idea how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can create in Google Tag Manager a javascript custom variable to measure time and use that value when sending the clic on external link or event you already have.

Take a look to [this article](https://www.clickinsight.ca/about/blog/timer-listeners-google-tag-manager) with the javascript example